# Counts days excluding weekdays and holidays

Tags: javascript

I know that this question is been asked a lot of time , but please help i am not able to find the solution

with the code below i am able to calculate no of days excluding weekdays

Now i want to also exclude public holidays says for eg 08/15/2012 , 09/12/2012 , 12/20/2012 , please help

```
function namet()
 {

        var iWeeks, iDateDiff, iAdjust = 0;

        var nodays = document.getElementById("timestamp1").value;


        var nodays1 = document.getElementById("timestamp").value;



        var dDate1 = new Date(nodays1);



        var dDate2 = new Date(nodays);





        if (dDate2 < dDate1) {

            alert("End Date : Enter date more than Start Date ");
        }
        // error code if dates transposed

        var iWeekday1 = dDate1.getDay(); // day of week



        var iWeekday2 = dDate2.getDay();
        iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday1; // change Sunday from 0 to 7
        iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 == 0) ? 7 : iWeekday2;
        if ((iWeekday1 > 5) && (iWeekday2 > 5)) iAdjust = 1; // adjustment if both days on weekend
        iWeekday1 = (iWeekday1 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday1; // only count weekdays
        iWeekday2 = (iWeekday2 > 5) ? 5 : iWeekday2;

        // calculate differnece in weeks (1000mS * 60sec * 60min * 24hrs * 7 days = 604800000)
        iWeeks = Math.floor((dDate2.getTime() - dDate1.getTime()) / 604800000)

        if (iWeekday1 <= iWeekday2) {
          iDateDiff = (iWeeks * 5) + (iWeekday2 - iWeekday1)
        } else {
          iDateDiff = ((iWeeks + 1) * 5) - (iWeekday1 - iWeekday2)
        }

        iDateDiff -= iAdjust // take into account both days on weekend

        var final = (iDateDiff + 1); // add 1 because dates are inclusive

        document.leaveapplication.noofdays3.value = final;
```

Comment: What are the public holidays. You need to specify. It varies from time to time, country to country

Comment: I assume you mean 'excluding week*ends* and holidays', because holidays fall on weekdays as a rule.

Comment: yes say for example the public holidays are : 08/15/2012 , 09/20/2012 , 12/20/2012 and also exclude the weekdays that is saturday and sundays

Answer (score 0):

You will need a list of holidays which fall on weekdays.

1. Calculate days between start and end
2. Calculate weekends between start and end (days modulo 7, then adjust for the positions in the final week)
3. Count all the holidays in your list between the dates and subtract that too.

Comment: Dear Phil , If possible can you please modify the code which will exclude the weekdays and holidays and please send the full code , please help